# Initialize complex number JAVA

Tags: java

I want to ask, how can I   initiallize final fields  ONE and ZERO, if I want to use them as neutral elements for addition and multiplication like in Ring

They must be costantly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Az3l.png)

```
public class ComplexNumber {


/**Constant for multiplication. Value 1*/
//public final ComplexNumber ONE;
/**Constant for addition. Value 0 */
//public final ComplexNumber ZERO; 
/**The real value of ComplexNumber! FINAL*/
private final double a;
/**The imaginary value of ComplexNumber! FINAL*/
private final double b;

/**
 * This Constructor initializes real and imaginary values  of ComplexNumber
 * @param a double real value
 * @param b double imaginary value 
 */
ComplexNumber(double a, double b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    //this.ONE = new ComplexNumber(1,0); //TODO ask
//  this.ZERO = new ComplexNumber(0);
}
/**
 * This Constructor initializes imaginary value of CompexNumber
 * @param b double imaginary value
 */
ComplexNumber(double b){
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = b;
    //this.ONE = new ComplexNumber(1,0); //TODO ask
//  this.ZERO = new ComplexNumber(0);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make constants out of them, declare and initialize them like this:

```
public static final ComplexNumber ONE = new ComplexNumber(1, 0);
public static final ComplexNumber ZERO = new ComplexNumber(0, 0);
```

`static` means that the field is class-specific and not instance-specific. `final` means the reference can't be reassigned. For a real constant, the instance must be immutable as well, which I think your code is doing since `a` and `b` are not accessible from outside your class.

Comment: But I don't like static in this case because, if I don't have any objects, I won't need constants! Or Am I not right?

But without static I have StackOverFlow Exception

Comment: @DmitrySavkin You won't instantiate the constants if you never use the class. Static fields are initialized the first time you'll be using the class. Anyhow, it's a constant, so you should declare it static. The StackOverflowException is normal as you're instantiating a ComplexNumber in the construction process of a ComplexNumber, so you're in a recursive call that goes deeper and deeper without turning point.

Answer (score 0):

only `constructor` is the way to initialize your `final` variables in Java.

because A final can only be initialize once of its life Cycle you cannot re-initialize it again .

So, Calling Constructor using parameter is a best way to initialize.

Comment: When I initialize them into the constructor, I'll have StackOverFlowException!

'code'


public class ComplexNumber {


 /**Constant for multiplication. Value 1*/
 public final ComplexNumber ONE;
 /**Constant for addition. Value 0 */
 public static final ComplexNumber ZERO = new ComplexNumber(0,0); 
 
 
 /**The real value of ComplexNumber! FINAL*/
 private final double a;
 
 
 /**The imaginary value of ComplexNumber! FINAL*/
 private final double b;
 ComplexNumber(double a, double b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
   this.ONE = new ComplexNumber(1,0);
   
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ComplexNumber {
        final double realPart;
        final double imgPart;

        public static final ComplexNumber REAL_ONE = new ComplexNumber(1, 0);
        public static final ComplexNumber ZERO = new ComplexNumber(0, 0);

        public ComplexNumber(double realPart, double imgPart) {
             this.realPart = realPart;
             this.imgPart = imgPart;
        }

        public ComplexNumber(double imgPart) {
             this(0, imgPart);
        }
    }
```

To make your code readable you can rename your field names to real and img part.
And use constructor chaining so that you can reuse the existing constructor.

**EDIT**

```
  public class ComplexNumber {
        final double realPart;
        final double imgPart;

        public static final ComplexNumber REAL_ONE = new ComplexNumber(1, 0);
        public static final ComplexNumber ZERO = new ComplexNumber(0, 0);

        public ComplexNumber(double realPart, double imgPart) {
            this.realPart = realPart;
            this.imgPart = imgPart;
        }

        public static ComplexNumber createRealComplexNumber(double realPart) {
            return new ComplexNumber(realPart, 0.0);
        }

        public static ComplexNumber createImgComplexNumber(double imgPart) {
            return new ComplexNumber(0.0, imgPart);
        }
    }
```

If you ever want to create a complex number with only real part, you'll not be able to overload constructor that only has real part, because the same signature is already being used. You can use this method

Comment: Using the method suggested by @Timmos for initializing REAL_ONE & ZERO. Adding readability and constructor chaining on top of it